# Tracking Github Commits on Grafana

Tags: github, webhooks, grafana

I would like to create a graph of all the github commits on a repository using grafana. However Im not able to find any ways to send this data to grafana server. Are there any plugins or workarounds to get this data to grafana?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub has no push model, only pull model [through webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)

That means you need to have a server listening to **[push events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent)** in order to analyze the push and store it appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there any way I can setup grafana to listen directly to the push events of github?

Comment: @PabloEstrada you simply need to declare your Grafana server as listener on your GitHub repo, section webhook: see the tutorial https://developer.github.com/webhooks/creating/. But that means you need a listener (process which listens for GitHub events) which then will contact the actual Grafana process in order to update it. Grafana itself is not aware of GitHub directly.